# Show that all elements of a group are inversable

Tags: finite-groups

Let $E$ be a set , and let $f_a$ and $g_a$ be two functions such that for all $a \in E$ :

$$f_a : E \rightarrow E$$
 defined by  $ f_a(x)=ax$, and

$$g_a : E \rightarrow E$$  defined by 
$ g_a(x)=xa$.

**The Question is** **:** Suppose that $f_a$ and $g_a$ are surjective  for all  $a \in E$,  and  suppose $e$ is a neutral element in $E$, show that all elements of $E$ are invertible.

I tried starting like this :

Suppose that : $x(x^{-1}) = e$

So : $(x^{-1})x(x^{-1}) = (x^{-1})e$

$e(x^{-1}) = (x^{-1})e$

So that means $f(x^{-1}) = g(x^{-1})$ are both in $E$.

I think that my answer is not logical because I don't think I showed the proper proof.

Can I get some help on how to start this answer or maybe how I can go about solving it please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you write *exactly* what the problem states?  What you've doesn't really make much sense.  If f(x) = ax for all a in E then for a, b in E f(x) = ax = bx => a = axx^-1 = bxx^-1 = b which is impossible.

Comment: Or at least f(x) is not a function in that f(x) can equal both ax and bx which are not equal.  If so I don't know what an "application" is and I don't know what "inversable" means.

Comment: In the questions it has f with a little a at the bottom of it. So it's like f_a(x) if you know what I mean, I didn't know how to write it in Latex sorry.

Comment: Ok, I re-edited the questions with the proper writing.

Comment: Ah, that makes a significant difference!  It's not a single f for all elements but different f's for different elements.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the question is asking.  If E is a group then by definition all elements are invertable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to show that every element in  $E$ is invertible, So let  $a \in E$, required to show  $a$ is invertible in $E$.

As $e \in E$, and $f_a$is surjective, then there exists  $x \in E$, such that $f_a(x)=e$, so that $ax=e$, hence $a$ is left  invertible.

On the other hand, as $e \in E$, and $g_a $ is surjective, then there exists  $x' \in E$, such that $g_a(x')=e$, so that $x'a=e$, hence $a$ is right invertible.

Hence  $a$ is invertible .

Comment: So in other words, E was not defined to be a group?

Comment: @fleablood I editeed the quetion in a suitable form , however the OP didn't submit by edition yet !

Comment: Also, $x = x'$ in that case, since $(x'a)x = x'(x'a)$ (under the assumption of associativity, but if it's a group...)

Comment: @PaulPicard just let me check my knowledge, should  $x$ and $x'$ be equal to say that  $a$ is invertible ??  and sorry I dont get what did you wrote above.

Comment: @PaulPicard I don't think  $E$ is a group, otherwise every element is invertible .

Comment: @Nizar No, $a$ is invertible in $E$ if it has a left and a right inverse. So what you wrote is right. ($x$ and $x'$ can be different)

Comment: @PaulPicard so in your comment did you mean  $(x'a)x=x'(xa)$, or I misunderstood you ?

Comment: @Nizar Probably misunderstood since $ax = x'a = e$ means that $x'ax = x'x'a$.